# How can I see the arima and exponential smoothing models used to determine the 'best' predictions for hierarchical time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical, forecast

I want to model, and make predictions for hierarchical time series data in R but I want to be able to see what the performance / plots look like for multiple types of arima and exponential smoothing models, not just the 'best' one. For a functional example below I create a hierarchical time series with one top node, 2 middle nodes, and 5 bottom nodes.

```
library(forecast)
library(hts)

#create the bottom level time series
bts <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(500)), ncol=5, nrow=100))
#create the hierarchical time series
y <- hts(bts, nodes=list(2, c(3, 2)))
```

I know I can predict the hierarchical time series like so

```
#create forecast object
y_for <- forecast(y, h=10, fmethod='arima', method='mo', level=1)
#pull predictions from forecast object
y_pred <- aggts(y_for, forecasts=TRUE)
```

and this gives me predictions for each series using middle out aggregation and the `auto.arima()` function. But I want to be able to specify what model is making the predictions before they are aggregated / dis-aggregated to the top and bottom levels. Is this something that has an elegant solution developed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that is possible using `hts`. Take a look at `fable` and `fabletools` (new packages by the `forecast` author). The functions [reconcile](https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/reference/reconcile.html) and [aggregate_key](https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/reference/aggregate_key.html) do give you the flexibility you want, but you need a rewrite of your time series structure (turn into `tsibble`).

Comment: Thanks @Bas thats very helpful info. Would `aggregate_key` be able to handle the dis-aggregation or only the aggregation?

Comment: Not sure! I've only used it for aggregation.